# Compatibility Django 1.7.4 Python 3.4

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model, and I use a class based `CreateView`.
At submit I get an error:

> unorderable types: int() > str()

The same error at django-admin.

I use Django 1.7.4 and Python 3.4

How to solve this problem?

my View:

```
class CreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = HeatingPlant
    template_name = 'heizwerk/form.html'
```

my model:

```
class HeatingPlant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length="64")
    street = models.CharField("Straße", max_length="32")
    house_number = models.IntegerField("Hausnummer")
    zip = models.IntegerField("Postleitzahl")
    place = models.CharField("Ort", max_length="32")
    phone_number = models.CharField("Telefonnummer", max_length="32", blank=True)
    mail = models.CharField("E-Mail", max_length="64", blank=True)
    #bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, verbose_name="Bank", blank=True)
    BIC = models.CharField("BIC", max_length=32, blank=True)
    IBAN = models.CharField("IBAN", max_length=32 ,blank=True)
    manager = models.CharField("Geschäftsführer", max_length="32")
    Ust_ID = models.CharField("Ust ID", max_length=16)
    company_register_number = models.CharField("Firmenbuchnummer", max_length="32")
    last_reading = models.DateField("Datum letzte CSV-Auslese", blank=True, null=True)
    standard_discount = models.IntegerField("Standardrabatt", default=0)
    correction_factor = models.DecimalField("Korrekturfaktor", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Can you post your model and view code?

Comment: Yes, Django and Python 3.4 are compatible.

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MakZZnY8
here is the traceback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter `max_length` should be of type `int`, not `str`:

```
# name = models.CharField("Name", max_length="64")
#                                            ^  ^
  name = models.CharField("Name", max_length= 64)
```

The same for other fields